# Use of setTimeout() in creating web worker in html5

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I am following a tutorial on web worker at - http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp

Most of the things are clear to me but I don't know what is the purpose of using `setTimeout` function and how `postMessage(i)` is returning the value of `i` to `w.onmessage`.

Code -

```
var i = 0;

function timedCount() {
    i = i + 1;
    postMessage(i);
    setTimeout("timedCount()",500);
}

timedCount();
```

Can anyone please explain me the flow how this example is working ?

Comment: In your example setTimeout means that this function will be fired two times in a second (500ms = 0.5s), `i` is just a counter, it will increase every time function will be fired,

Comment: @zvone is `postMessage()` is a random name method or its a convention to use this method to pass value ?

Comment: @TechSolvr It's a standard. [`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) is a method that's defined by the browser for communicating with other documents, including Web Workers. The other document can receive the message by subscribing to the `message` event.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski okkk thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of `setTimeout` is to call `timedCount` after 500 ms. Since it is called recursively, the effect is that `timedCount` is called twice in each second.

Note also, that this would do the same:

```
var i = 0;

function timedCount() {
    i = i + 1;
    postMessage(i);
}

setInterval(timedCount, 500);
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining it in a simple term +1 and accepted !!

Answer (score 2):

```
function startWorker() {
    if(typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
        if(typeof(w) == "undefined") {
            w = new Worker("demo_workers.js");
        }
        w.onmessage = function(event) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = event.data;
        };
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry! No Web Worker support.";
    }
}
```

Notice the Call back registered on `w.onmessage`

> When the web worker posts a message, the code within the event
>   listener is executed. The data from the web worker is stored in
>   event.data.

and the Magic is Played by  `SetTimeout` Function which recursively post timer value at the interval of 500ms using the Global Method of `Webworker` ie. `PostMessage`

Full Details of PostMessage function can be found here

[PostMessage Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage)

> myWorker.postMessage(aMessage, transferList);

**Parameters**

**aMessage**

> The object to deliver to the worker; this will be in the data field in
>   the event delivered to the DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope.onmessage
>   handler. This may be any value or JavaScript object handled by the
>   structured clone algorithm, which includes cyclical references.

**transferList Optional**

> An optional array of Transferable objects to transfer ownership of. If
>   the ownership of an object is transferred, it becomes unusable
>   (neutered) in the context it was sent from and it becomes available
>   only to the worker it was sent to.

*Only MessagePort and ArrayBuffer objects can be transferred.*

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info +1

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the setTimeout() method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

```
var i = 0;

function timedCount() {
i = i + 1;
postMessage(i);
setTimeout("timedCount()",500);
}

timedCount();
```

The script above loads the function timedCount. The initial value for the variable i is 0. Following the equation, i is equated to 1 ( 0 + 1). The postMessage then show the value of i which is 1. Next is where setTimeout comes in.

setTimeout, based on the definition, will run the script after a 500-millisecond interval. Since the function timeCount is called in a loop, it will run the function in a continuous loop with the interval of 0.5 seconds in each run. It will count and show the value of i in an increment of 1 every 500 milliseconds.